# Quero mudar uma string em 3 posições

Tags: python, string

Gostaria de andar 3 posições com uma letra de uma *string*, por exemplo, fazer a letra A virar D, eu tentei o segundo comando:

```
texto[c] = texto[c] + 3
```

Porém ainda não funciona, qual seria o jeito correto de fazer?

Answer (score 6):

Se eu entendi, você quer fazer algo parecido com a cifra de Cesar. Dada uma string, você precisa andar com cada caractere mais 3 posições.

Você pode usar uma alfabeto de base, em python ele já está implementado por default em `string`

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alfabeto
```

assim você pode ter uma base para rotacionar. Beleza, temos uma base de strings. Então vamos pegar uma string para colocar no jogo:

```
string = 'stack'
```

As string tem um método chamado `.index` que vai te dar a posição de cada caractere. Por exemplo:

```
alfabeto.index('a')
# 0
```

assim você pode somar mais 3 e obter uma nova posição. No mesmo caso:

```
alfabeto[alfabeto.index('a') + 3]
# 'd'
```

Nesse caso, você pode iterar na string que quer rotacionar

```
for letra in 'stack':
    print(alfabeto[alfabeto.index(letra) + 3)
# 'v'
# 'w'
# 'd'
# 'f'
# 'n'
```

Dessa maneira você teria uma string toda rotacionada. Porém, existem alguns problemas, como se você tentar rotacionar 'z'

```
for letra in 'zzz':
    print(alfabeto[alfabeto.index(letra) + 3])
# IndexError: string index out of range
```

Porque sua string não tem uma posição maior do que 'z'. Então você poderia fazer um módulo usando o tamanho do seu alfabeto.

```
for letra in 'zzz':
    print(alfabeto[(alfabeto.index(letra) + 3)% len(alfabeto)])
#'c'
#'c'
#'c'
```

O que faria você sempre rodar o alfabeto todo somando mais três e iniciando com o mesmo caso ele estoure o tamanho da sua lista.

```
''.join([alfabeto[(alfabeto.index(letra) + 3)% len(alfabeto)] for letra in 'stackzz'])
# 'vwdfncc'
```

Answer (score 5):

Você tem que converter para número para fazer a conta (com [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)) e depois converter para caractere de novo (com [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)), assim:

```
def DeslocaASCII(texto):
    novoTexto = ''
    for letra in texto:
        numero = ord(letra)
        novoTexto += chr(numero + (-23 if numero > 87 else 3))
    return novoTexto
    
print(DeslocaASCII('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7kaRvS). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hyeogfta-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/GetASCIICode.py).

Estou considerando que só será enviado um texto com caracteres maiúsculos. A validação do texto entrado deveria ser feita em outro local para manter a responsabilidade única.

Não tentei resolver nada além do que está na pergunta para não especular onde será usado.

Comment: Olhando por essa perspectiva, dependendo dos caracteres eles podem não ser printáveis usando como base a tabela ASCII por exemplo.

Comment: Sim, editei para melhorar isto.

Answer (score 1):

```
def rot(s):
   return ''.join([chr(ord('A')+(ord(c)-ord('A')+3)%26) for c in s])
```

- dada uma letra `c`,`p=ord(c)-ord('A')` , dá a sua posição dentro das letras. p ∈ {0..25};
- `(p+3)%26` soma 3 circularmente dentro do segmento `[0..25]`;
- `chr(p + ord('A'))` dá a letra correspondente à posição `p`;
- `ord('A')+(ord(c)-ord('A')+3)%26` soma 3 circulamente dentro do semento ['A'..'Z']
- `[ soma3(c) for c in s]` calcula a lista das letras rodadas presentes em `s`
- `''.join(lista)` reconstroi a string já rodada.

Os amantes das respostas ilegíveis poderão ainda substituir ord('A') obtendo:

```
def r(s): return ''.join([chr(65+(ord(c)-10)%26) for c in s])
```

Comment: @Isac, obrigado pela sugestão explicativa; O que é isso de "sinalizar"? Por quem? Para quem ver?

Comment: Sinalizar é indicar a publicação para analise de outros. Existem [várias filas de analise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review) uma para cada tipo. Qualquer pessoa pode sinalizar e qualquer pessoa pode analisar. Algumas filas requerem reputação para analisar, como a fila de baixa qualidade que requer 2000 pontos. Nunca é possível de saber quem sinalizou. Acho que a frase que melhor resume o principio é a que aparece inicialmente na página das filas de análise: "Stack Overflow em Português é moderado por você."

Comment: @isac, obrigado. Faz-me lembrar a ASAE ☺...